# Django Form Generation filtering foreign key data

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form based on a Model, e.g. car. The model has a foreignkey Parts.
I am trying to generate a form but filter the parts on 'available' = True. I can't find a way to do this (without generating it manually).

Is there a way to filter the form, like a .filter() on an object?

```
class Car(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
parts= models.ForeignKey(Parts,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Parts(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
available= models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self)
    return self.name
```

And the form:-

```
  form = CarForm()
```

And the template is using crispy forms

```
        {% crispy form %}
```

Comment: It is quite odd that you define a `ForeignKey` from `Car` to `Parts`, that means a `Car` can only have one `Part`?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the choices with [**`limit_choices_to=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parts = models.ForeignKey(
        Parts, limit_choices_to={'available': True}, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

That being said, It is quite odd that you define a `ForeignKey` from `Car` to `Parts`, that means a `Car` can only have one `Part`?

Comment: thanks so much. Can it be limited on a form generation basis ? rather than in the model across the app? For example I render the model in different places, for users I want to limit the selection but not in the backend